# Override VBA macro in Excel long enough to save very same macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a prefilled template that has ".NC" that needs numbers added in front of the ".NC" before it can be saved (example 12345678.NC).  Maybe I am going about this the wrong way but..  I tried to make it alert if only ">NC" is in the box, problem is ".NC" is prefilled in the template sheet and needs to be there, this then flags my macro and will not allow me to save the very macro stopiing it from saving!  My code works, it works so well that I cannot save my code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L3").Value = ".NC" Then
Cancel = True
         MsgBox ("Please enter program number")
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there a way to override that macro just long enough to save it? Maybe I am just going about this all wrong..

Comment: NVM, I didn't realize that I could pause the macro in VB long enough to save the excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. When a user clicks the save button this run and prompt them to fill out that cell if the cell does not have ".NC" or is less than 3 characters long.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    With Range("L3")
        If Len(.Value2) <= 3 Or Right$(.Value2, 3) <> ".NC" Then
            'MsgBox ("Please enter program number")
            .Value2 = InputBox("Please enter program number") & ".NC"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```